# How to insert custom id to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
addPortfolio: async (portfolio) => {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, `portfolios`), portfolio);
    return docRef;
}
```

I am adding ID as `1667071357` but it is inserting some random id into it.
How can i keep this as my id.
Please check the below screenshot.

I am using this code to insert data to firebase collection.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of add() use set(), where you can add ID as document reference, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Answer (score 1):

While you are using Firebase V9 you can use

```
// Get the collection reference
const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(),'portfolios');

// Generate "locally" a new document for the given collection reference
const docRef = doc(collectionRef); 

// Get the new document Id
const documentUuid = docRef.id;

//  Sets the new document with its uuid as property
await setDoc(docRef, { uuid: documentUuid, ... })
```

Above example generate automatically document ID to create custom ID just assign it to document reference.

```js
const docRef = doc(collectionRef, 'here your custom ID');
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: Did you change the 'yourFirestoreDb' ?

Comment: It is as it is.

Comment: I have made an edit to the code check it now

Comment: attached `docRef ` response in screenshot. Please check

Comment: @Salem_Raouf Your ID in a document have a `.` in it, it might be not allowed to assign to document ID. Generate IDs with no special characters or check in firebase documentation if It's allowed to use dots as ID.

Comment: portfolio.id.toFixed()

Comment: I am doing this already

Comment: I suggest to use nano Id library to generate your random IDs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid